# SVG hover event doesn't fire when sibling item in the way

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG element with multiple child items.  I can easily replace the fill for a particular element on hover by looking for the `:hover` CSS property.  But if a sibling element exists on top of the hovered element, it prevents the hover from bubbling up to other elements.

Here's an example.  The circle's gradient will be replaced when hovering over the circle.  But get anywhere near the text and it will revert back to the original color.

```css
.circ:hover { 
    fill: url(#surfaceGradientHover);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     width="300" height="200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
      <radialGradient id="surfaceGradient"
           cx=".6" cy="0.2" r=".8">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" />
          <stop offset="50%" stop-color="red" />
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="maroon" />
      </radialGradient>
      <radialGradient id="surfaceGradientHover"
           cx=".6" cy="0.2" r=".8">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" />
          <stop offset="40%" stop-color="red" />
          <stop offset="80%" stop-color="maroon" />
      </radialGradient>
  </defs>

  <circle class="circ" cx="150" cy="100" r="80"
          fill="url(#surfaceGradient)" />

  <text x="150" y="125" font-size="50" 
         text-anchor="middle" fill="white" 
         transform="translate(-10,5)rotate(-5)">
             easy
  </text>

</svg>
```

Comment: Put the hover on the SVG instead `svg:hover circ` etc.

Comment: @Paulie_D, yeah, but then the effect triggers anywhere over the entire svg, instead of just over the circle...

Comment: But that's what you want isn't it.

Comment: @Paulie_D, no.  Perhaps bubble up wasn't the best word.  Bubble Over?  I'd like the circle to act like a button and change colors when hovering over it.  But if you're also hovering over the text, it will get in the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to group the `circle` and `text`.

```css
.shape:hover .circ {
  fill: url(#surfaceGradientHover);
}
.shape {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="surfaceGradient" cx=".6" cy="0.2" r=".8">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="maroon" />
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="surfaceGradientHover" cx=".6" cy="0.2" r=".8">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="40%" stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="80%" stop-color="maroon" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <g class="shape">
    <circle class="circ" cx="150" cy="100" r="80" fill="url(#surfaceGradient)" />
    <text x="150" y="125" font-size="50" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" transform="translate(-10,5)rotate(-5)">
      easy
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

So one way to solve this would be to prevent the text from catching mouse events by using `pointer-events`:

```css
.text {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

But the implementation is [still a little spotty in IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) and it prevents a user from interacting with the text if they might want to.  So a better solution would be nice.

```css
.circ:hover { 
    fill: url(#surfaceGradientHover);
}
.text {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     width="300" height="200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
      <radialGradient id="surfaceGradient"
           cx=".6" cy="0.2" r=".8">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" />
          <stop offset="50%" stop-color="red" />
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="maroon" />
      </radialGradient>
      <radialGradient id="surfaceGradientHover"
           cx=".6" cy="0.2" r=".8">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" />
          <stop offset="40%" stop-color="red" />
          <stop offset="80%" stop-color="maroon" />
      </radialGradient>
  </defs>

  <circle class="circ" cx="150" cy="100" r="80"
          fill="url(#surfaceGradient)" />

  <text class="text" x="150" y="125" font-size="50" 
         text-anchor="middle" fill="white" 
         transform="translate(-10,5)rotate(-5)">
             easy
  </text>

</svg>
```